# Custom Loss and Slicing (Keras R)

Tags: r, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I am trying to write a simple custom loss in Keras [R] and experiencing a bit of trouble. Consider a simple network that output a vector of dimension 2, for example

```
  model <- keras_model_sequential() 
  model %>% layer_dense(units = 2, input_shape = c(1))
```

Now, let us suppose (I know, that is silly) that one would like a loss that reads:

```
                      LOSS = (y_truth - y_pred[1])**2
```

where y_truth is 1-dimensional, and y_pred, the output of the network, is 2-dimensional (so, one completely ignore the second dimension). The following does not seem to work:

```
my_loss <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  K <- backend()
  loss <- K$mean( K$pow(y_true - y_pred[,1],2))) 
  return(loss)
}
```

I have tried a few variants, without success. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

PS: what I'm really trying to do is write a loss function that would give me a Gaussian log-likelihood. The output of the network would be the mean and log_variance...

[EDIT]
it seems that the following variant works:

```
my_loss <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  K <- backend()
  loss <- K$mean( K$pow(y_true - y_pred[,1:2],2))) 
  return(loss)
}
```